# ld: version node not found for symbol

Tags: c, makefile, linker, ld, linker-scripts

I've looked through google and can't find anything exactly like my problem, so any help is appreciated.

Error Message:
`ld: main.efi.so: version node not found for symbol ??_C@_15JNBOKNOG@?$AA?$AN?$AA?6?$AA?$AA@`

Full Output:

```
ld -nostdlib -shared -Bsymbolic -Luefi uefi/crt_x86_64.o main.o -o main.efi.so -luefi -T uefi/elf_x86_64_efi.lds
ld: main.efi.so: version node not found for symbol ??_C@_15JNBOKNOG@?$AA?$AN?$AA?6?$AA?$AA@
ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
make: *** [uefi/Makefile:89: main.efi.so] Error 1
```

Makefile 1:

```
ARCH = x86_64
TARGET = main.efi
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
CFLAGS = -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror --ansi -O2

USE_GCC = 1
include uefi/Makefile
```

[Makefile 2 (Included in first)](https://pastebin.com/D72ueVHP)

[elf_x86_64_efi.lds/linker script](https://pastebin.com/dwcaxrLR)

Comment: The 'LD' utility processes the parameters from left to right, so the object file(s) must be listed before the library paths and library names

Comment: @user3629249 I think they are? I'm not great with makefiles but the line that executes the linker command is ```$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS)``` which looks like it's correct

Comment: regarding macros lijke: `CFLAGS = -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror --ansi -O2`  1) the `--ansi` parameter is not a good idea,  Suggest removing that parameter. 2) to avoid having `make` re-evaluate the macro reach time it is referenced, replace the `=` with `:=`